# How to judge a window exsits?

Tags: java, windows, swing, jframe, exists

could return boolean?
I want to new a JFrame if the JFrame not exsits,but not to new if exsits.
I creat a Map to save JFrame's name.

Comment: Could you post a response to our answers, or accept one to close the question if we helped you?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern#Java) frame. It would look somewhat like

```
class MyFrame extends JFrame {

   private static MyFrame frame;

   private  MyFrame() {}

   public static MyFrame getInstance() {

      if ( frame == null ) {
          frame = new MyFrame();
      }
      return frame;

   }


}
```